# Making base class protected constructor public in derived class

Tags: c++, c++17

Can someone please explain why the marked line does not compile? It seems to me that if `B2` and `D` compile, `B1` should too.

```cpp
class A1 {
  protected:
    A1(int){}
};
class B1 : private A1 {
  public:
    using A1::A1;
};

class A2 {
  protected:
    A2(int){}
};
class B2 : private A2 {
  public:
    B2(int i) : A2(i) {}
};

class C {
  protected:
    void f(int) {}
};
class D : private C {
  public:
    using C::f;
};

int main() {
    // B1 b1(1); // error: calling a protected constructor of class 'A1'
    B2 b2(1);

    D d;
    d.f(1);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what section of the class `using` declaration is placed into. Inherited constructors preserve their original visibility. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration): "If overload resolution selects an inherited constructor, it is accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class: the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced it is ignored."

Comment: In contrast, `using` declaration for members other than constructors does change visibility: "Using-declaration introduces a member of a base class into the derived class definition, such as to expose a protected member of base as public member of derived." That's why `using C::f;` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*using-declaration* behaves differently when designating constructors vs other members. For constructors, the visibility of the *using-declaration* is ignored; if selected by overload resolution, the constructor can be used if it's visible in the base class. For all other members, *using-declaration* introduces a synonym into the derived class' scope, and that synonym has the visibility of the *using-declaration*.

> **[namespace.udecl]/19** A synonym created by a *using-declaration* has the usual accessibility for a *member-declaration*. A *using-declarator* that names a constructor does not create a synonym; instead, the additional constructors are accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class, and the accessibility of the *using-declaration* is ignored.